# Mui DataGrid update cellValue depending on other cell

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Hi I would to change cellValue on other cellChange in a editMode="row" Datagrid Mui.

Here my code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-brook-c4kwk5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I would to add the logic to edit data1 and data2 in my handleFlagOneChange function.

I'm trying to use apiRef.current.setEditCellValue but it require id of the other cell that I don't have.